# Keep the color of selected <li>'s a tag after page refresh

Tags: jquery, html

I made one toggle menu in which I have to save that state after page refresh.

In that menu there are three step. First **select sport**. After **select country**. And at end **select league**.

Now in this **league** there is a  `<li>` with `<a>` tag. So What I exactly want is when someone select my li tag so that li should be in orange color after redirect.

but when user select that li and my page is redirect and all li looks in same color.

Here is my **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wasimkazi/CGsJH/2/)**.

here is my script.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();
 $jq(document).ready(function(){
 $jq(".widget2").hide();
 $jq(".inner").hide();

function getCookie(c_name) {
    var i, x, y, ARRcookies = document.cookie.split(";");
    for (i = 0; i < ARRcookies.length; i++) {
        x = ARRcookies[i].substr(0, ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
        y = ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=") + 1);
        x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
        if (x == c_name) {
            return unescape(y);
        }
    }
}

function setCookie(c_name, value, exdays) {
    var exdate = new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays === null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

var widget2 = $jq(".widget2");
var box2 = $jq(".box2");
if (getCookie('box2id') || getCookie('box1text')) {
    var text = getCookie('box1text');        
    var id = getCookie('box2id');
     $jq('#' + id).addClass("disable");
     $jq('#' + id).next().slideDown(600, function() {  
     $jq('.box:contains('+text+')').next('.inner').slideDown(500);
     jq('.box:contains('+text+')').next('.inner').css('color', 'green');    
    });
} else {
    $jq(".widget2").hide();
    $jq(".inner").hide();
}

box2.click(function() {
    $jq(this).next(widget2).slideToggle(200);
    $jq(".widget2").not($jq(this).next(widget2)).stop(true, false).slideUp();
     var box2ID = $jq(this).attr('id');
     $jq(this).add(".disable").toggleClass("disable");
     setCookie('box2id', box2ID);        
  });

$jq(".box").click(function() {
    $jq(this).next(".inner").slideToggle(200);
    var box1TX = $jq(this).text();
    setCookie('box1text', box1TX);         
});
});

});​
```

Answer (score 1):

First build it without JS, then add the JS and use some pushState magic to map the URLs correctly for browsers that support it.

Comment: have you seen my example.. it'working live at my site now I just want to keep it's li's color which one last selected.
please check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wasimkazi/CGsJH/2/).

Comment: Yes, I had a quick look, and the simplest way I can see to achieve this would be to do what I suggested. If you can get it to work without the js then add back in your existing js and augment with some pushState magic (eg. https://github.com/balupton/History.js/). That way it will work for everyone.